# Calling super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) in a fractions.Fraction subclass accepts only the instance to initialize

Tags: python, inheritance, variadic-functions, super, python-fractions

```
from fractions import Fraction


class F1(Fraction):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Fraction.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class F2(Fraction):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


Fraction(1, 10) # Fraction(1, 10)

F1(1, 10) # F1(1, 10)

F2(1, 10) # TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

How does this happen? Could someone elaborate a bit on the super function?

Python version: 3.8.10

Comment: I don't know the full answer, but `Fraction` is an immutable that is created with `__new__` and not initialized with `__init__`. To subclass you need to play the `__new__` game and typically not implement `__init__`. See `Fraction.py` and what it does. I'd guess that _both_ F1 and F2 examples should fail. I can't explain why F1 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; `Fraction` uses `__new__` instead of `__init__`.

Python objects are assembled in two steps. First, they are created with `__new__` and then they are initialized with `__init__`. Usually we use the default `object.__new__` to create a new empty object and then override `__init__` for anything special that needs to be done.

But some classes want to control the object creation step by implementing their own `__new__`. This is especially the case for immutable classes like `Fraction`. `Fraction.__new__` returns an object of its own super class and when that happens, python skips calling `__init__` completely. In the case of `Fraction`, its `__init__` is really just `object.__init__` which only accepts the single `self` parameter and just returns without doing anything. It is never meant to be called.

When you implemented `F1.__init__`, you had a bug and this bug masks the problem. When you call a superclass method directly, you need to put the `self` parameter in the call. You should have done `Fraction.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`. Had you done so, you'd get the same error as in the `F2` case (because `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` *does* add the `self`).

But really you have a more pressing problem. Its okay to have your own `__init__`, but with restrictions. You can't initialize the `Fraction` because that was done in `__new__` before `__init__` was called. And you can't call `Fraction.__init__` which does nothing except explode when given parameters. You could add other attributes to the object, but that's about it. But other strange things will happen. Unless you override methods like `__add__`, they will return objects of the original `Fraction` type because that's the `__new__` that is being called. When your parent class uses `__new__`, you really want to override that `__new__`.

Comment: An important point: The *reason* `Fraction` uses `__new__` is because all logically immutable objects should use `__new__`, not `__init__`, and all the immutable types that ship with Python obey this rule (e.g. `int`, `float`, `str`, `tuple`; if you subclass them, you need to override `__new__`, not `__init__`). The reason being that `__init__` can be called again and change the state (there are some weird nooks in the language that do this on purpose), while `__new__` (which does not receive an existing instance) can't mutate an existing instance.

Comment: @tdelaney any comment on the F1.__init__() bug ? had to ask coz i went on a langauge data model safari for getting this answer, and i still cant figure the bug

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Thanks for fleshing that out,

Comment: @Cpreet - The basic problem is that `Fraction.__init__` is an invalid call. Had it been written as `Fraction.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` (you need to supply the `self` yourself in this case), you'd see the same error as the `F2` case. `Fraction.__init__` is really just `object.__init__`, which does nothing. As written, python passes the `arg` tuple as the first parameter and since `object.__init__` does nothing, the fact this its the arg tuple and not `self` is not discovered.

Comment: @Cpreet - I was surprised by this. When making the call, python pushes args as a tuple and kwargs as a dict on the stack and then calls the function. The function call step expands these into the parameter list of the function. Why this expansion worked when `object.__init__` doesn't have extra parameters is still puzzling to me.

Comment: Exactly, @tdelaney, i was able to puzzle together that the mro goes through the tree and calls object init, but rn with the 2 agruments it still works as a normal Fraction instance. Is it a big enough to be submitted to the python git ? Nicely explained tho